# How far can where conditions go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm using a where statement to pull records with a few conditions.

Currently it looks like this:

```
humans.where("? <= created_at AND created_at <= ?", value.days.ago.beginning_of_day, value.days.ago.end_of_day)
```

I'm wondering as to where I can extend it like this without it being invalid:

```
humans.where("? <= created_at AND created_at <= ? AND subscribed = ? AND provider != ?", value.days.ago.beginning_of_day, value.days.ago.end_of_day, true, 'twitter')
```

Will this still work? Are queries like this Postgres compatable?

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to add another `AND` clause to your query. This should work. I like the rails syntax so I'd separate the parts I can use the rails syntax to a separate part:

```
humans.where("? <= created_at AND ....", value.days.ago.beginning_of_day, true, 'twitter')
      .where(subscribed: value.days.ago.end_of_day)
```

In fact if you prefer that syntax you can convert more of your query to it (approx. like that):

```
humans.where(Human.arel_table[:created_at].gteq(value.days.ago.beginning_of_day))
      .where(Human.arel_table[:subscribed].lteq(value.days.ago.end_of_day))
      .where(subscribed: true)
      .where(provider: 'twitter')
```

Comment: Excellent mate, keeps things clean! Any idea if these queries are postgres compatible?

Comment: I use these queries with postgres all of the time.